# Disallow Skype from showing icons next to phone numbers

Tags: icons, skype

Is it possible to *stop Skype from adding it's icons* next to phone numbers on a website?

Comment: are you asking how you can craft HTML so that the Skype plugin won't augment the page, or simply how to turn off that feature of the plugin?

Comment: This is not programming related at all. RTFM.

Comment: @InsertNickHere not necessarily if she wants to disable the icons to show up on clients' machines when visiting a page she is building. Give folks a chance to add detail before voting to close, all.

Comment: @Pekka I dident vote for close and I will not - maybe this turns out to be a programming question,but at this time its not.

Comment: @Insert that's true. The OP will need to clarify.

Comment: Of course this is a programming question. You cant dictate what crap a client has installed on their machine but you are still expected to control the experience.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the skype addin in Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: In IE, go to "Tools" (I guess, I've a German Windows ;-)), "Manage Add Ons". There's a Skype addon where you have to click on and then "Deactivate".

In Firefox it's under Tools -> AddOns.

Hope that helped.

But anyway, you can also reinstall it and unselect the Skype Addons in the setup :-)